# "&#xE100" values in StandardStyles

Tags: xml, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Sorry for the confusing title, but I'm not sure what to call those. I'm talking about this:

```
<Style x:Key="SkipBackAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="SkipBackAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Skip Back"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE100;"/> <!-- This one -->
</Style>
```

There are several of those in StandardStyles.xaml, but I have no idea how it works, any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are XML/hex-encoded Unicode characters in the Segoe UI font. Basically icons in form of typeface glyps. There is a "Styles Browser" app in the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) that shows all the icons, including the full set of 150 icons that Tim Heuer shared in his [blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/05/visualizing-appbar-command-styles-windows-8.aspx).

Comment: Aaaah that's really clever! I thought it was some sort of new way to get a resource or something. Thanks!